# I accidentally created a higher level rails app, Is there a way to remove the Rails part of the folder but to keep the folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My C:/Users/MyName folder is a Rails application somehow and I cannot make a new rails app inside this.

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks.

I receive the following error message when I run the "rails new newAppName" command:

"can't initialize a new rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non rails directory"

Comment: i think you are inside the rails application and creating new application inside existing application ..make sure you are outsite the rails application when you are creating new app..

Comment: I don't want to be outside this folder though. I wan to to remove the rails app aspect of the folder.

Comment: You should be able to fix it by navigating up to the directory where you accidentally created the rails application and delete the folders and files that it created (e.g.: app, config, db, Gemfile, etc.)

Comment: Thank you Coenwulf, right after I asked the question I concluded that there are files such as that you have mentioned in the directory. I am  "almost" certain that I have removed all the necessary files. so far, it has not worked, will update if anything changes. Maybe I have missed a file.

Comment: Are there any hidden files? (on Windows: Start > Folder options > display hidden files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to a directory outside `C:/Users/MyName` and type:

```
rails new anything --pretend
```

This will give you a list of all the files and directories rails wants to create for a new application.  The `--pretend` flag stops it actually creating them.  Then work through this list and delete the corresponding files from C:/Users/MyName`

Comment: I have followed a similar method but I think i may have taken too much out now as no Rails apps will start when I run "rails s".

Comment: Did you make your new rails app in the correct place?  If you are seeing the help page for `rails new` when you type `rails s` it means you are not in a rails app directory when you try to start the server.

Comment: Graeme, I am seeing this page when i run "rails s" but I believe I am in a Rails app directory when I run it. I think i am making progress though. Will get back to you, Thanks.

Comment: My existing rails apps work when I run them but when I clone a rails app from github and try to run it, it won't work.

Comment: I am happy that I have fixed the problem by finding and deleting the rails files but I did not do it via the method above exactly.

Comment: No problem; you can edit my answer if you need to change a detail (or tell me and I can edit it).  Please make your new problem about cloning a rails app from github a new question - better to have separate problems separate as it makes it easier for others to find a solution later.  You should give details about steps you did to clone, and what error you get when you try to run it so we can help.